# rails dynamically generate a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, model-view-controller

I'm pretty new to the whole rails MVC concept, and I've been tasked with creating a form which does the following:

- takes a test number
- shows how many sections there are per test (this is a constant, always 4)
- allows a region for the user to enter in their responses for each question in a section. The number of questions in each section changes depending on the test number they get.

I have my view which looks like this:

```
  = form_for [@answer_sheet] do |f|
      =f.collection_select(:test_prep_number, Exam.find(:all),:test_prep_number, :test_prep_number, {:include_blank => 'Select your test prep number'})
      =f.fields_for :answer_sections do |section_form|
         =section_form.label :section
              .form-inline
             =f.label :A 
             =radio_button_tag 'answer', 'A'
             =f.label :B
             =radio_button_tag 'answer', 'B'
             =f.label :C
             =radio_button_tag 'answer', 'C'
             =f.label :D
             =radio_button_tag 'answer', 'D'
             =f.label :E
             =radio_button_tag 'answer', 'E'
```

My controller looks like this:

```
def index
    @answer_sheet = AnswerSheet.build_with_answer_sections
    @answer_section = AnswerSection.new
    @section_count = AnswerSection.where("exam_id = ?", params[:test_prep_number).count
end
```

The issue I'm having right now is I can't seem to wrap my head around creating the correct number of radio buttons. So far, I've managed to generate only one question per section.

I'm assuming I'll need a for loop (which will then require a query to find how many questions per exam section).

Edit: Adding models as requested

**Answer sheet model**

```
class AnswerSheet < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :date, :raw_score, :test_prep_number, :answer_sections, answer_sections_attributes
MAX = 101
validates :test_prep_number, :presence => true
validates :raw_score, :presence => true, :numericality => { :greater_than_or_equal_to => 0, :less_than_or_equal_to => MAX}
validates :date, :timeliness => {:on_or_before => lambda { Date.current }, :type => :date}, :presence => true
belongs_to :user
has_many :answer_sections
```

**Answer Section model**

```
class AnswerSection < ActiveRecord::Base
  MAX = 30

  attr_accessible :section_score, :answers, :answer_attributes
  has_many :answers, :dependent => :destroy
  belongs_to :answer_sheet
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers

  validates :section_score, :presence => true, :numericality => { :greater_than_or_equal_to => 0,
:less_than_or_equal_to => MAX }
```

Comment: What is the relationship between the AnswerSheet and the AnswerSection models?

Comment: AnswerSheet contains many AnswerSections, and each AnswerSection belongs to a single AnswerSheet.

Comment: Can you share both of those models with me?

Comment: yeah sure just added them

Comment: I'm a little unclear, is this a test taking app or an app that displays test answers.  Depending on your answer I think there is a better way to organize your models.

Comment: it's a test taking app; a user inputs the answers to the questions, then on submit, i grade them accordingly

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend tweaking your models to something the breaks the choice from the users answer:

```
class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :question

  attr_accessible :date, :test_prep_number

  validates :test_prep_number, :presence => true
  validates :date, :timeliness => {:on_or_before => lambda { Date.current }, :type => :date}, :presence => true
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  MAX = 30

  attr_accessible :question_text
  has_many :choices, :dependent => :destroy
  has_one :answer
  belongs_to :test
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers

end

class Choice < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :question_id, :choice_text, :correct_choice
  belongs_to :question
end

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :choice_id
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :question 
end
```